# Which is a better starter camera?

Tags: camera-basics

for someone just starting with the goal of doing family photos, weddingd, etc.which would be a better starter Nikon d3000 or Sony a350

Comment: @Jody did you try first searching on this website before posting the question? If so, why would the other question not address your problem or why would the answers offered there not give you an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This may become a religious debate, but I'd go for the D3000. Nikon has a broad line of lenses and camera bodies- much more of a selection than Sony. If you truly want to move towards becoming a professional (and you -must- approach weddings in a professional way else woe and heartbreak will follow :-) then Nikon is the way to go. 
If you continue with photography in a serious way then your lens purchases are going to be much more important than your camera body purchases. Camera bodies come and go but lenses are (almost) forever. I have a Nikon 50mm 1.4 that I purchased in 1973 that is still perfectly usable on most of the current Nikon bodies. For an A/B comparison of the two see [this site](http://www.imaging-resource.com/cameras/sony/dslr-a350/vs/nikon/d3000/).

Comment: Offopic. BobT, does your camera recognizes when your old 1.4 lens is in focus?

Comment: I don't have the lens with me at the moment but I'm pretty sure the "In Focus" dot and arrows show when the lens is focused properly on my D800. My old 105 2.5 works great as well. Here's a description of how it works- http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/48720/11772